# Что не так с запросом к PostgreSQL ? (psycopg2 SyntaxError: syntax error at or near column_name)

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, psycopg2

Добавил поле "authorization" (обычный CharField) к модели и после этого отправка запроса (INSERT) начала выдавать ошибку psycopg2 SyntaxError: syntax error at or near authorization, а до этого все прекрасно отправлялось. Все миграции нового поля сделаны.

Вот поле:

```
authorization = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

Вот запрос:

```
"INSERT INTO main_keys (authorization, end_datetime, key) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", ('0', (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(),))
```

Повторюсь до того как добавил поле "authorization" запрос прекрасно выполнялся, а сейчас выдает ошибку

Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо

Comment: А тот же запрос через консоль?

Comment: @Akina тоже, хз вообще почему. Проверял, что хочешь уже, в упор не понимаю почему так. Очень странно. Запрос, кстати, отправляется к PostgreSQL, которая на Heroku

Comment: Нашёл. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-keywords-appendix.html Квотируй - или переименуй.

Comment: @Akina точняк, надо было ж слово выбрать :) спасибо тебе большое